# Bulk conversion VSDX files to VSD

Tags: file, ms-office, converters, bulk

is there any elegant way for bulk conversion of VSDX files to VSD?
Please note - it's actual downgrade, not the other way around.
Is it achievable by scripting?
Or am I left for 3rd party tools..?
Many thanks
Kind regards

Comment: You need just change extension to vsd or open these documents in older versions ?

Comment: @Surrogate - Nope, hard-way change of extension results in error message upon file opening.

Comment: Of course, because vsdx document have different file structure! Which Visio version you have ?

Comment: You can't convert vsdx documents if you haven't installed Visio on your PC. Or you need write your own converter !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA Macro in Visio file will do it...

```
Sub Converter()
Dim StrFile As String
    Dim objFSO, destRow As Long
    Dim mainFolder, mySubFolder
    Dim fullPathFileName
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    mFolder = "C:\Users\sivancik001\Desktop\vsdx\" ' <<<< PATH TO BE CHANGED !!!!
    Set mainFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(mFolder)
    StrFile = Dir(mFolder & "*.vsdx*")
    'Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        '... actions here ... but not needed as nothing should be in the root folder. files are in subfolders
        'StrFile = Dir
    'Loop
    For Each mySubFolder In mainFolder.SubFolders
        StrFile = Dir(mySubFolder & "\*.vsdx*")
        Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
            fullPathFileName = mySubFolder & "\" & StrFile
            'MsgBox fullPathFileName
            Application.Documents.Open fullPathFileName
            Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Left(fullPathFileName, Len(fullPathFileName) - 1)
            Application.ActiveDocument.Close
            Kill fullPathFileName
            StrFile = Dir
        Loop
    Next
End Sub
```